# UITapGestureRecognizer not working in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

This may seem really simple, but I've been tearing my hair out for a while now wondering why this isn't working. I'm trying to change the image when tapped on, but it doesn't seem to recognise the tap at all. I have enabled user interaction both on the storyboard and programatically, so am a little lost.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tL.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    x = UIImage(named: "Cross.jpg")
    reset = UIImage(named: "white.png")

    //Tap Gesture ------------------------------------------------------------

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Logic))
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    tL.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func Logic(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    tappedView.image = x
    print("Image Tapped")
}
```

Comment: Don't nest your `Logic` function inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Edited. It's not actually inside, I cut out a lot of code due to it not being needed. Still not working.

Comment: UITapGestureRecoginzer works fine in swift3. Your code, if gestureRecognizer is inside viewDidLoad() and func logic is outside viewDidLoad() should works fine too. Issue is something else.

Comment: How is "tL" added? Is it obscured by any other view?

Comment: @SwiftBeginner Did you figure this out im having the exact same issue,

Answer (score 3):

fun Logic needs 1 argument, you should provide as such in your selector. Change from

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Logic))
```

to

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourClassName.Logic(_ : )))
```